# Postgres Query taking long time

Tags: postgresql

I have this SQL query which takes long time (~12s) to execute:

```
select nextval('rec_id_seq_af') as rec_id,ds_id,ds_dt_id,
inv_vcf_id,inv_sample_id,inv_variant_id,ds_dt_line_seq from rs_data_1_af 
group by ds_id,ds_dt_id,inv_vcf_id,inv_sample_id,inv_variant_id,ds_dt_line_seq 
order by ds_id,ds_dt_id,inv_vcf_id,inv_sample_id,inv_variant_id,ds_dt_line_seq;
```

When I run:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
select nextval('rec_id_seq_af') as rec_id,ds_id,ds_dt_id,
inv_vcf_id,inv_sample_id,inv_variant_id,ds_dt_line_seq from rs_data_1_af 
group by ds_id,ds_dt_id,inv_vcf_id,inv_sample_id,inv_variant_id,ds_dt_line_seq 
order by ds_id,ds_dt_id,inv_vcf_id,inv_sample_id,inv_variant_id,ds_dt_line_seq;
```

This is the output:

```
Group  (cost=724728.48..780477.07 rows=314077 width=88) (actual time=10395.641..12546.322 rows=5703 loops=1)
  Group Key: ds_id, ds_dt_id, inv_vcf_id, inv_sample_id, inv_variant_id, ds_dt_line_seq
  Buffers: shared hit=80975, temp read=91041 written=91171
  ->  Sort  (cost=724728.48..732580.39 rows=3140766 width=80) (actual time=10395.619..12019.351 rows=3140766 loops=1)
        Sort Key: ds_id, ds_dt_id, inv_vcf_id, inv_sample_id, inv_variant_id, ds_dt_line_seq
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 286312kB
        Buffers: shared hit=75272, temp read=91041 written=91171
        ->  Seq Scan on rs_data_1_af  (cost=0.00..106679.66 rows=3140766 width=80) (actual time=0.009..575.729 rows=3140766 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=75272
Planning Time: 0.478 ms
Execution Time: 12581.964 ms
```

When the records in rs_data_1_af table increases, I would have million of rows, this query takes hours to execute.

How can I optimize?

Comment: The grouping/sorting is done on disk, you need to increase `work_mem`

Comment: My current work_mem is 4MB. What should be ideal?

Comment: Did you try making a btree index? `create index on rs_data_1_af (ds_id,ds_dt_id,inv_vcf_id,inv_sample_id,inv_variant_id,ds_dt_line_seq);

Comment: @karianpour I haven't. Should I?

Comment: @dang, why not ! But it has some writing overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you running `nextval('rec_id_seq_af')`?

`nextval()` advances the index and returns the next value. For each row it has to do that, read/write in isolation, no wonder it is slow.

What is the purpose there, perhaps you can use `generate_series()` or something else?

Comment: `nextval()` does not work under transaction isolation and is extremely fast. But do agree that it seems strange to use it in that context. The major reason for the slowness is the sort done on disk